# BroadcastReceiver becoming unregistered after child Activity finished

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am starting a child preference activity from the main activity using `startActivityForResult`. In the child `Activity`, where the user can set preferences, I register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive an intent broadcasted from a one time alarm. When the user finishes setting their preferences, the child activity finishes and exits back to the main activity screen. The problem I'm having is how to have the `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the child `Activity` continue to be active waiting for an intent from the `Alarm` that was activated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a service registered for receiving intent broadcasts. The service was terminated when an intent was received and handled (by the OnReceive method). What I did to overcome this problem is to (re)start the service at the end of the OnReceive method. Maybe you can do a similar thing in your activity, or migrate it to a service if this is not possible.